# Не могу создать подключение к Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

Имеется следующая строка подключения

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=LEVAN-PC;Initial Catalog=Cars Integrated Security=True Trusted Connection=True";
```

Имеется сервер с базой данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше идёт следующий код.С помощью которого я подключаюсь к базе данных.

```
 SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\C#\ADO.NET\Text.txt", ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlcon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("ConnectionClosed");
        }
```

Но выводиться следующий exception

> Login failed for user ''.

поле User пустое. В интернете пишут добавить данный `login` в `Security-logins`, но пустой логин там не добавляется.

Comment: А) У вас после `Cars` отсутствует `;` Б) Попробуйте пропишите явно логин в поле `User ID` строки подключения

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из комментариев

> А) У вас после `Cars` отсутствует `;`
>
> Б) Попробуйте пропишите явно логин в поле `User ID` строки подключения

от *[LbISS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186112/lbiss)*

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо явно указать логин и пароль в строке подключения.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?